# Proving Combinatorics Statements

Tags: combinatorics

I am given this problem:

Assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove:

(a.) $C_0^n + C_1^n + \dots + C_n^n = 2^n$

(b.) $C_0^n - C_1^n + \dots + (-1)^n C_n^n = 0$

I know when I do the math for both problems, they're both true statements, but I don't think I can provide a proof by doing an example. I'm not sure about the second question, but would I be able to prove the first by induction?

Comment: Do you mean $C_n^0 ...$?

Comment: Should these be $_n C_k$ i.e. binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, I mean either one. I'm not too good with the Math formatting yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the binomial theorem, they both follow from that:

$$(a+b)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^kb^{n-k}$$

where ${n \choose k} = C_k^n$

Then $a=b=1$ yields your first identity:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 1^k1^{n-k} = (1+1)^n = 2^n$$

Letting $a=-1$ and $b=1$ yields your other identity.

If you aren't allowed to use the binomial theorem, induction isn't a bad way to go.